# Swift 2&3: How to Use CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I have the following code:

```
let ref:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil , 200, 130, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0, CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage))
```

The problem is that I get this error:

Expression does not conform to type 'NilLieralConvertible'

What should I pass in instead of nil for the first argument and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the *last* argument. Make the last argument `CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue`.

Comment: It's because the nature of bitmask types has completely changed in Swift 2.0. And CGBitmapInfo is a bitmask type.

Comment: Works for Swift 3 too